# how can I recompile vim with certain python version?

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

in vim, I typed this to check which python version vim is using.

```
python3 << EOL
import sys
print(sys.version)
EOL
```

Then I got this message, so I know vim is currently using **python3.5.2**

```
3.5.2 (default, Jul 17 2020, 14:04:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

But I need to use at least **python3.6** so that I could use **YouCompleteMe Plugin**.

So, **how can I recompile vim with certain python version(upper python3.6)**? googled It but couldn't found any tips.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-3.x%5D+%5Bvim%5D+compile